# Opening app from Android causes "stacking" of Activities

Tags: android, out-of-memory

1. I open my app from launcher - Activity A is launched
2. Inside Activity A, I open B (which is a map, that uses lots of bitmaps, therefore lots of memory)
3. I open Android Market, go to my app in the Market, and click "Open", which launches Activity A of my app
4. I open Activity B. Activity stack is now. OutOfMemoryException is thrown, because **both** activities B are using about 90 item bitmap cache.

The question is obvious - how to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure that's what happening? Log some message in onCreate() and check if it isn't called in loop. Android should kill background activities when it needs some memory. Also, which device are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fhucho Did you tried [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) or this [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) which says

> If set, the activity will not be
>   launched if it is already running at
>   the top of the history stack.

Hope it helps